# Codeigniter - get related data rows as structures/objects, not array

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Im a newbie in CodeIgniter.

I have created model for Pizza table and Ingredients table. Tables are joined by additional Pizza_Ingredients table (its many to many relation).

My model:

```
<?php

class Pizza extends DataMapper {

    var $table = 'Pizza';

    var $has_many = 
        array(
        'ingredients' => 
            array(
            'class' => 'ingredients',
            'join_table' => 'pizza_ingredients'
            )
        );
}

class Ingredients extends DataMapper {

    var $table = 'Ingredients';
    var $has_many = 
        array(
            'pizza' => 
                array(
                'class' => 'pizza',
                'join_table' => 'pizza_ingredients'
             )
        );
}

?>
```

When I get data using that code:

```
$pm = new Pizza();
$pm->include_related('ingredients');
$array = $pm->get();
```

im getting array which has duplicated Pizza values (it looks like just sql query result).

```
margherita    | cheese
vegetariana   | vegetable 1
vegetariana   | vegetable 2
```

I can't simple generate html table in "foreach" on array like this.

i want to get object, that has structure like this:

```
margherita:
 - cheese

vegetariana:
 - vegetable 1
 - vegetable 2
```

that allows me to make foreach loop (with pizzas) with other foreach loop (with ingredients) inside "pizza loop".

I have to write this in PHP, or CodeIgniter/DataMapper can do something more for me?

Any advice?

Comment: I think this has more to do with your get method than the class/methods you show above. In your get method simply set the keys for your array to the pizza you return from the DB. Than as ingredients come in you will be appending the pizza array instead of having a new array for each pizza for each ingredient.

Comment: Ok, so i have to write custom accessor for my pizza. But how to do it efficient and in CodeIgniter-style? Can someone put little example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just stuck in the same answer...

So, searching the CI Datamapper DOCs, I found something that will help (http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html), look at the first example!

Translating to your problem, should be like this:

```php
    // Create pizza

    $pm = new Pizza();

    // DO NOT USE include_related to Ingredients Here !!!
    //Datamapper will DO THIS for you!
    // Remember to declare your Ingredients class in singular, not plural
    // So your class should be in singular -> Ingredient
    // And your DB Table should be in plural -> Ingredients
    // As CI Datamapper Guide teaches :)

    // Get all pizzas

    $pm->get();

    // Loop through all pizzas

    foreach ($pm as $pizza)
    {

    // Print the actual pizza name

            echo $pizza->name."<br/>";

            // Get the current pizza's Ingredients  <- Here is the magic comes!

            $pizza->ingredient->get();

            // Print all current pizza's Ingredients

            foreach ($pizza->ingredient as $ingredient)
            {
                    echo $ingredient->name."<br/>";
            }
    }
```

This work very well to me, but it continues to hit the db a lot of times, actually, one time for each pizza that your DB contains.

I really appreciate if some solution using CI Datamapper took less requests to DB.

Please share if you find it!

Comment: I think the best way to do it right may be big SQL query with joins. Only problem is format of data returned by query - its record set, not "tree structure".

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an intermediary table to break down the many to many relationship.  Seems much easier to manage.  Like:

```
TABLE pizza_ingredients
   id
   pizza_id
   ingredient_id
```

Then you can try something like this:

```
foreach($pizzas as $pizza)
    $pizza->ingredients = $this->get_ingredients($pizza->id);
```

Comment: If you mean loop on pizza_ingredients rows - seems to be good idea, but i think get_igredients should work on buffered data from one query, not run 30 queries like "get ingredient where ...". you know what i mean?

Comment: If you have 30 pizzas, yes, you would hit the db 31 times. Not ideal. Why not just ignore the duplicate pizza names? You try to play with nested select's at the sql level, something like: select x, y (select z ...) ...  These type of queries take some trial and error. But in the end, a single query return rows, not nested data.

Comment: I can get all data from that 3 tables (pizza, relation table, ingredients) and put them into arrays. Then make some foreach on relation array and i will make only 3 queries. But i have time, maybe someone will come up with better idea...

Answer (score -1):

You could set a variable that is the pizza you are currently on and check it on your next iteration. Your formatting and whatnot would vary but this will give you an idea.

```
foreach ($pizza as $k=>$p) {
    if ($last_pizza === $p->pizza) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                $p->cheese
            </td>
        </tr>";
        $last_pizza = $p->pizza;
    }else{
        echo "<tr>
            <td>
                $p->pizza
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                $p->cheese
            </td>
        </tr>";
        $last_pizza = $p->pizza;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not that what im looking for,  but i probably use similar code for building my "pizza_with_ingredients" object. I cant believe there is better way...