# Getting field value from object array by key inside object

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.2

This is very stupid question and I can't believe that im asking about something simple like this.

Im using `db->get['table']->result()` to get data from table.

Table schema looks like this: table(id, col1, col2).

`db->get['table']->result()` returns something like this (print_r):

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [col1] => "id 1 col 1"
        [col2] => "id 1 col 2"
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [col1] => "id 2 col 1"
        [col2] => "id 2 col 2"
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [col1] => "id 3 col 1"
        [col2] => "id 3 col 2"
    )
}
```

Now i need to get col2 value from row that has id=2, i want to do it without "foreach" loop.

I thought i can do it like this:

```
$valueThatINeed = $myArray[2]->col2;
```

This is wrong and i know why its wrong.

Question is - how to directly get that what i need without loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
my_filter($array,$ID) {
     $col2 = array_values(array_filter($array, function($arrayValue) use($ID) { return $arrayValue[0] == $ID; } ));
     if (count($col2) > 0) {
        return $col2[0][2];
     } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$col2 = my_filter($arr,2);
```

Comment: 1. Can you make it easier to understand? 2. My ID's are unique, there is no way to get multiple results. 3. Is this more efficient that searching for id by loop?

Comment: It looks like in PHP 5 i can't write something like this: `function($arrayValue) use($ID)`, or i cant put function body there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you could probably use array_uintersect with a callback function that compares just the $id property but it's a bit clumsy, and probably no faster than a simple for loop.

Perhaps we should come at this from a different angle... Probably the most efficient way to find the right record is to fire a SELECT query at the database - after all that's exactly what databases are optimised for, especially as the id column will be indexed (assuming id is the primary key).

Original post:

> I assume it's not just as simple as:
>
> $valueThatINeed = $myArray[2]->$col2;

Comment: its not, because this is something like this:
`$valueThatINeed = $myArray[array_index]->otherArray` where array_index starts with 0 and its not equal to table id.

Comment: Had a feeling it wouldn't be ;) I will amend my answer to include another suggestion.

Comment: Original idea was normal query with joins. You can see my tries here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054474/codeigniter-get-related-data-rows-as-structures-objects-not-array Then i tried to make joins in PHP, not sql and build tree in PHP, because returned data was not in "objective" format, just records. I was worried about big foreach that ruin performance. Maybe i will back to that query and process it in loop and build "tree" from query anyway...